# Unable to install ng2-charts via npm

Tags: npm, chart.js, npm-install, ng2-charts

I have an issue when trying to install ng2-charts package using the commande:

```
npm install ng2-charts@2.3.2
```

the version of ng2-charts we have in nexus is 2.3.2, and the version of chartjs dependency is 2.9.3

```
720 verbose pkgid @types/chart.js@^2.7.48
721 verbose cwd C:\Users\d55356\bancasFrontend
722 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
723 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ng2-charts@2.3.2"
724 verbose node v14.17.5
725 verbose npm  v6.14.14
726 error code E404
727 error 404 Not Found - GET https://nexus-url/repository/npm-group/@types/chart.js/-/chart.js-2.9.23.tgz
728 error 404
729 error 404 '@types/chart.js@^2.7.48' is not in the npm registry.
```

Is there a way to force the chartjs version <2.9.3> when installing ng2-charts <2.3.2> package?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use

npm install ng2-charts --save --legacy-peer-deps to ignore all the dependencies and make a bar chart. But if you want to make a doughnut chart you will face some problems with

import { MultiDataSet, Label } from 'ng2-charts';
from component.ts

I face the same problem hope someone can help with this.